# Assign Empty Charges to Top Active Contract

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a user who entered charges for customers but didn't assign those specific charges to a contract.

The charges are all $135 and entered on a specific date. There are two tables I need to get info from, t_ARLineItem (Charge Details), and t_Owner (Owner Items) I've written the following code to find those affected:

```
SELECT charge.ARLineItemID, charge.ContractID, charge.Amount, charge.DueDate, charge.UserName, owner.OwnerID, owner.OwnerNumber, owner.FirstName, owner.LastName FROM t_ARLineItem charge 
JOIN t_Owner owner
on charge.OwnerID = owner.OwnerID
WHERE charge.Amount = '135' AND charge.DueDate = '6/24/2019' AND charge.ContractID = '0' AND
charge.OwnerID IN ('OwnerID', 'OwnerID', ...)
```

This returns the following (~2,000):

```
ARLineItemID | ContractID | Amount | DueDate | UserName | OwnerID | FirstName | LastName
-------------|------------|--------|---------|----------|---------|-----------|--------
123          | 0          | 135.00 | 6/24/19 | User     | 5       | Name      | Name
124          | 0          | 135.00 | 6/24/19 | User     | 8       | Name      | Name
```

I need to assign each charge with no ContractID to the top active contract for that Owner. Each OwnerID can have multiple contracts, I need to set the charge the latest Active Contract. That table for contracts is t_Contract and is structured as:

```
ContractID | OwnerID | ContractNumber | ContractDate | ContractStatus
-----------|---------|----------------|--------------|----------------
100        | 5       | 100            | 2015-05-15   | Active
151        | 5       | 151            | 2017-11-29   | Inactive
165        | 5       | 165            | 2019-05-25   | Active
```

In this example, OwnerID 5 would need Charge ID 123 assigned to Contract 165.

```
ARLineItemID | ContractID | Amount | DueDate | UserName | OwnerID | FirstName | LastName
-------------|------------|--------|---------|----------|---------|-----------|--------
123          | 165        | 135.00 | 6/24/19 | User     | 5       | Name      | Name
```

**Edit:** I've gotten this far with help from the community, but I cannot get it to work

```
UPDATE t_ARLineItem
SET ContractID = latestActiveContract.ContractID
FROM t_ARLineItem charge 
    JOIN t_Owner owner ON charge.OwnerID = owner.OwnerID
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM t_Contract c 
        WHERE c.OwnerID = owner.OwnerID
            AND c.ContractStatus = 'Active'
        ORDER BY c.ContractDate DESC
    ) latestActiveContract
WHERE 
    charge.Amount = '135' 
    AND charge.DueDate = '6/24/2019' 
    AND charge.ContractID = '0' 
    AND charge.OwnerID = '16014'
```

Comment: *I've gotten this far with help from the community, but I cannot get it to work* ... is not a helpful description. Please describe errors or undesired result. You need to place the alias, *charge*, in `UPDATE` command.

Comment: I've tried ```UPDATE charge SET``` but that doesn't actually set the cell. I apologize for not being clear. It says two cells are updated, but the ContractID isn't set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `CROSS APPLY` with `TOP 1` and `ORDER BY` you can match the charge to the newest active contract:

```
UPDATE charge
SET charge.ContractID = latestActiveContract.ContractID
FROM t_ARLineItem charge 
    JOIN t_Owner owner ON charge.OwnerID = owner.OwnerID
    CROSS APPLY (
        SELECT TOP 1 *
        FROM t_Contract c 
        WHERE c.OwnerID = owner.OwnerID
            AND c.ContractStatus = 'Active'
        ORDER BY c.ContractDate DESC
    ) latestActiveContract
WHERE 
    charge.Amount = '135' 
    AND charge.DueDate = '6/24/2019' 
    AND charge.ContractID = '0' 
    AND charge.OwnerID IN ('5', '8')
```

Comment: That shows the correct contract number, but I need to set the Contract ID for the charge.

Comment: see my edited answer.  if that doesn't work for you, explain what exactly isn't working and we can help you

Comment: I get ```(1 row(s) affected)``` 2 times and it doesn't actually update the ContractID in the t_ARLineItem field. I might have to create a function in Excel and do it that way.

Comment: There was something program specific not allowing this. This is the working solution!